# Pattern Matching using brute force in openCL

Tags: opencl, string-matching, workgroup

I have stored the text in char array a[textLength], and pattern in an array b[patternLength]

```
cl_char *a = (cl_char *) malloc(textLength*sizeof(cl_char));

for(int i =0; i<textLength;i++)
{
    a[i]=text[i];
    }

// A buffer object is a handle to a region of memory
cl_mem a_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                 CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | // buffer object read only for kernel
                                 CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, // copy data from memory referenced
                                 // by host pointer
                                 textLength*sizeof(cl_char), // size in bytes of buffer object
                                 a, // host pointer
                                 NULL); // no error code returned

// for text and pattern kernal arguments
cl_char *b = (cl_char *) malloc(patternLength*sizeof(cl_char));

for(int i =0; i<patternLength;i++)
{
   b[i]=pattern[i];
}

// A buffer object is a handle to a region of memory
/*cl_mem b_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                 CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | // buffer object read only for kernel
                                 CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, // copy data from memory referenced
                                 // by host pointer
                                 patternLength*sizeof(cl_char), // size in bytes of buffer object
                                 b, // host pointer
                                 NULL); // no error code returned */
cl_mem b_buffer = NULL;


    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(a_buffer), (void*) &a_buffer);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, n, sizeof(cl_mem), &b_buffer);
    size_t global_work_size = numberofWorkItem;
    cl_int error= clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel,
                       1, NULL, // global work items dimensions and offset
                       &global_work_size, // number of global work items
                       &patternLength, // number of local work items
                       0, NULL, // don't wait on any events to complete
                       &timeEvent); // no event object returned

 I have read that in clSetKernelArg, for __local indentifiers, the arg_value should be NULL. I have done that by doing b_buffer=NULL;
```

But doing that would prevent the b_buffer from storing the value of b[] (pattern)
How do I do it??

Also,
If I am not wrong, the  local_work_size can not be greater than the value given by CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES. Because the local_work_size is constrained by the underlying device/hardware.
The global_work_size, on the other hand, can be as big as one wants.
Does it have to be a multiple of local_work_size ???
If yes, why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in the clSetKernelArg line:

```
//incorrect
clSetKernelArg(kernel, n, sizeof(cl_mem), &b_buffer);

//correct
clSetKernelArg(kernel, n, sizeof(cl_char)*patternLength, NULL);
```

Local memory is cleared after kernel execution, so you won't be able to get a copy of b_buffer using your method. Also, local memory is not assigned by the host. You need to copy from a global parameter to get it into the LDS.

To get the local data copied, you need to pass in a global cl_mem as well as the local parameter. The copy can be done at the end of the kernel and red back to the host with clEnqueueReadBuffer.

**Update**

Here's a specific example of how to use a dynamic local buffer, and assign it the contents of a global buffer.

```
__kernel void copyBufferExample(__global int* srcBuff, __local int* localBuff, const int copyCount)
{
    int lid = get_local_id(0);
    int ls = get_local_size(0);
    int i;

    for(i=lid; i<copyCount; i+=ls){
        localBuff[i] = srcBuff[i];
    }

    //use localBuff here
    //copy result back to global memory if needed
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering :)    
    cl_mem b_buffer = NULL;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(a_buffer), (void*) &a_buffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), NULL);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, n, sizeof(cl_mem), &b_buffer);
The above lines are wrong?
Can you please explain how to assign the local memory? If it is not assigned by the host?

Comment: You need to pass the data in as a global, as well as an uninitialized local buffer and let the kernel copy + use the data. I posted an update above showing kernel code which does this.

Comment: Since the Global_work_group size is related to the problem size (suppose in pattern matching, I take it (Length_of_text)-(Length_of_pattern)) And I take the Local_work_group size as Length_of_pattern(only 1 word). But IF the Global_work_group size is not a multiple of Local_work_group,and since it must be a multiple, I cannot take the LWG to be Length_of_pattern.How should I pass the Pattern in __Local then?

Comment: I normally consider a single pattern lookup to be a task for a single work group. If you only have one word to find, it may not be a job for gpu.

Comment: I understand, but I am trying to convert a simple pattern matching program to parallel using __Local.But I don't know where the __local will be used..I thought that it should be used to store the pattern..
Will __Local be used only for passing multiple patterns??

Comment: That's something you need to determine with experimentation. You could store any combination of data in local and tweak it to work for you (needle / haystack / haystack chunk). Your algorithm should be designed with the typical number of sub strings and the size of the text in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The code above doesn't do the copy in parallel ...

this does ...

_*kernel void copyBufferExample(*_global int* srcBuff, __local int* localBuff, const int copyCount)
{

```
int i = get_local_id(0);
```

if ( i < copyCount)
       localBuff[i] = srcBuff[i]; //  each thread copies 1 int. No for loop needed

```
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);  // synchronize all threads before using the local memory


//use localBuff here
//copy result back to global memory if needed
```

}

Comment: Does it have to be while(i<copyCount) ?? because each value of srcBuff has to be copied to localBuff??

Comment: If your GWG size in the x dimension is > copyCount this works! Why?  because you launch more threads(kernels) than copyCount. Each thread copies 1 int.  All these threads run in parallel